# Serverless database on .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, database, sqlite

Im working in a small desktop project which is going to need a serverless database structure because it is going to be used in a shared Dropbox folder, and i cant install SQL server in every PC thats going to use it.

My idea is something like a database file in dropbox, where someone could update info and upload the file into the Dropbox Folder, the rest of the users just read the data from there, but i dont know exactly what should i use for the database.

I read about some options like SQLite and make a XML to store data, but i want to know what could be the best and simplest approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I like SQL Server.  You can send the mdf file so everybody can have a copy of the file.  It is very easy to create a database then deattach the file from database and make copies.  Then reattach file to same server or different server.  You can actually put multiple copies of the mdf file on same server (different database names) so each user would have their own copy of the data and not have to send file.

Comment: But you can load directly the mdf file and read data from it?

Comment: Yes.  You can use the System.Data.SqlClient class to connect to database either on a local machine or a remote machine.  You have to setup credentials properly.   You can download SQL Server for free and either put one copy on a server and have everybody use same server with different database.  Or install SQL Server on each user machine and send copy of mdf to each user.

Comment: Thats the problem, the idea is using somehting without a server and without installing sql server in every machine. If that´s possible

Comment: Then load server on one machine and have everybody connect to the one machine.  Make it easy to change to database on the one machine.  Visual Studio also allows a local db (also an mdf file) if it is better to send copy of mdf to each user.  Just need a different connection string.

Comment: That isnt an option either, thats why i was looking for something like a file DB or text file as Database

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources (like a DBMS) are off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic].

Comment: The SQL Server database mdf is a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of Litedb? It creates a file with db extension. You can install it from a nuget package. Is basically a library project. Mongo like server less dB https://www.litedb.org/

Get started here https://www.litedb.org/docs/getting-started/. You just need to install the nuget package before hands.

Some more information on this post https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.infoworld.com/article/3253115/how-to-work-with-litedb-in-c.amp.html there is plenty out there anyways, very light and very easy to use. I am browsing in bed on my mobile phone. If I was on my pc I would put few snippets and examples myself. I'll create apsnet core project tomorrow using litedb update this with link to my github where you can find fully working example.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried with the examples of the link, and i think im going to go with this. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Nice, glad I could help. One thing that comes to mind, if you need to have the db accessed by different processes and you initialise connection once, make sure you specify in your connection string the type as shared. ConnectionString offers other solutions as well, such as protection with password. https://www.litedb.org/docs/connection-string/

Comment: Cool, i will look into that. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't able to install SQL Server on all the machines, then I've used and can recommend Sqlite. (I've previously written Point of Sale/Till software in .net which uses SqlLite as a local database, polling when it could up to a SQL Server via a webservice. There was a requirement that the system could keep operating without internet. This was at least 10 years ago. The systems are still in use.)

Anyway, all that to say that I've found Sqllite to be rock solid and fast enough. [HERE's](http://zetcode.com/csharp/sqlite/) a quick summary of use with C#. One tip is to always distribute the command line version with your app, so during the early teething days you can always access the database in a command window and check what's happening.

(I would have just added this to comments, but don't have enough rep yet)