# how to running c# application without create setup file?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, desktop-application

I want to create a desktop application with database, am using Visual Studio 2015 and C# connected to local database , Can i run this application without create installation file
and with out installing any database server in client's system [ie, with out installing MsSql server or MySql server or Acess],

ex if move application by flash memory or cd drive to another pc i need  start (run) application  normally  with all data saved in database

can i apply this idea or not available  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serverless database on .NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464358/serverless-database-on-net-c-sharp)

Comment: If it's going to connect to a database, you need to have a database somewhere you can connect to. Generally the database you will be connecting to is described by a _connection string_ that describes how to connect and what identity the program will use for the connection. If it's a simple desktop program, you usually don't need a specialized installation program. If it runs the. NET Framework, then that will need to be pre-installed on the target machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cloud DB. If your client has an internet connection, your app works finely. On the other hand, you can copy the Debug folder, then whereever you paste it, your app is works there.